# Oracle SQL query to return row values if all rows have some value in column after grouping by another column

Tags: sql, oracle10g, group-by

I have some data that looks like this -

```
ColA     ColB    ColC
ID1      1       '1-1'
ID2      1       '2-1'
ID2      0       '2-2'
ID3      1       '3-1'
ID3      1       '3-2
```

I need a query (for Oracle 10g) that groups rows by the value of ColA and then returns the values of ColC concatenated ONLY IF all rows in the group have ColB=1. So the output I want for the given data would be -

```
"1-1"
"3-1,3-2"
```

Any suggestions for how to write a query like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Search for **group_concat function in oracle**

Comment: @Dhinakaran: `group_concat` is available in MySQL. In Oracle there are `wm_concat` and `LISTAGG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT colA, wm_concat(ColC)
    FROM table_name
   WHERE colB = 1
GROUP BY colA;
```

**EDIT** - You can also use LISTAGG aggregate function like this:

```
  SELECT colA, LISTAGG(colC, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ColC)
    FROM table_name
   WHERE colB = 1
GROUP BY colA;
```

I would recommend using LISTAGG as it is documented by Oracle whereas wm_concat is not.

**EDIT :** If it's the case that you don't want rows like ID2 to show as it has one row with ColB = 0, or, colB != 1, you can have:

```
  SELECT colA, wm_concat(ColC)
    FROM table_name t1
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM table_name t2
                      WHERE colB != 1 -- Or, you can give colB = 0
                        AND t2.ColA = t1.ColA)
GROUP BY colA
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - wish LISTAGG was there in 10g! But I think this query will return rows which belong to a group where some row contains a ColB value other than 1? In my example above, I don't want any ID2 rows to be returned because row 2-2 has ColB=0.

Comment: Do you mean, if ID2 contains even one row with ColB = 0, you don't want it to show in the result, right? Please confirm so I can edit my answer. It will need a little re-phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Oracle10g` then

```
select o1 from (select wm_concat(c3) o1,wm_concat(c2) o2 from table group by c1)
where length(o2)-length(replace(o2,'0',''))=0
```

for `11g`

```
select o1 from (select listagg(c2,',') within group (order by c1) o2,
listagg(c3,',') within group (order by c1) o1 from table group by c1)
where length(o2)-length(replace(o2,'0',''))=0
```